# right align self.navigationItem setTitleView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I need to align the navigationItem TitleView to the far right. (where the navigationItem rightBarButtonItem normally appears)

How can this be done ?

I have tried this but with no luck it still places TitleView in the center:

```
CGRect titleViewPos = CGRectMake(300, 0, 200, 10);
self.navigationItem.titleView.frame = titleViewPos;
```

Comment: add as a subview then.

Answer (score 4):

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbl.text = @"TITLEVIEW";
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbl;
```

You will get output as

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 btn.frame = CGRectMake(300, 0, 200, 10);
 [btn setTitle:@"titleView" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.navigationItem.titleView = btn;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a UIElement (UIView,UILabel) to navigation item then you can set the position and make other customisation with navigation title  or left button or right button.
May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, May be use-full

```
 UILabel *lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,40)];
lbNavTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
lbNavTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lbNavTitle.text = @"hello World";
self.navigationItem.titleView = lbNavTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

The titleview frame is automatically adjusted, if you want to obtain this result you can try this:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame];
[titleLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
[titleLabel setText:@"Your title"];
[titleLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[titleLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

NOTE: be sure to don't set self.title of your view controller otherwise you will overwrite the titleView

Another solution could be put the titleLabel into an UIBarButtonItem (customView) and set it like to self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem in this way you don't need to set the text alignement ad the frame of the label can be the proper text size

Answer (score 0):

none of that worked for me. I took Desdanova's advice and just added as a subview. Makes sense because that's all it is! Initialize it with any frame position you want and then

```
[self.view addSubView:lbl];
```

and Voila!